# Inserção de dados com um proc no SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, tsql

[image: Tabelas do banco]
Preciso usar um procedimento que adicione dados na tabela `Pedido` e depois na tabela `ItemPedido` de forma automática. Porém não estou conseguindo criar uma *procedure* que funcione.

Segue abaixo meu código:

```
create procedure [dbo].[add_pedido] 
                             (@codcli int,
                              @quant varchar(50),
                              @data date,
                              @codprod int,
                              @codpedido int)
as insert into Pedido (CodCli, Data_pedido) 
   values (@codcli, @data)
   insert into ItemPedido (Quant_pedido, CodProduto, CodPedido) 
   values (@quant, @codprod, @codpedido)
```

É inserido no banco os dados de Pedido, porém os dados para ItemPedido não são inseridos. Para executar, utilizo o código a seguir:

```
EXEC add_pedido 
    @quant = 2, @data = '23/02/2020', @codprod = 4, @codcli = 5, @codpedido = @@IDENTITY;
```

E eu preciso que ItemPedido herde o CodPedido, mas não consigo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O acontece aí é que a primeira inserção ocorre com sucesso. Porém, na segunda, ocorre um erro porque o valor de `@codprod` é **`NULL`**.

Isso é causado pelo lugar em que é usado o `@@IDENTITY`.

Esta função retorna o último valor de identidade (*identity*) **após alguma operação** (inserção, neste caso).

Seu código não funciona porque você executa `@@IDENTITY` **antes de ter inserido qualquer coisa**.

[Na documentação você pode encontrar maiores detalhes sobre o `**@@IDENTITY**`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/identity-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15).

Você também pode evitar que os dados sejam inseridos numa tabela e não na outra usando uma transação. Isso vai fazer com que a operação seja [atômica](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atomicity_(database_systems)) e, desta forma, a operação como um todo só será bem sucedida se todas as operações funcionarem.

A versão abaixo funciona como esperado.

```sql
ALTER PROCEDURE Add_Pedido (@codcli INT,
                              @quant VARCHAR(50),
                              @data DATE,
                              @codprod INT)
AS
    BEGIN TRAN
    INSERT INTO Pedido (CodCli, Data_pedido) 
    VALUES (@codcli, @data);

    INSERT INTO ItemPedido (Quant_pedido, CodProduto, CodPedido) 
    VALUES (@quant, @codprod, @@IDENTITY)
    COMMIT TRAN;
```

<sup>[**Veja funcionando no SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/9a892/1)</sup>

Comment: Valeu amigo, funcionou